# PHP unzip no external libraries

Tags: php, zip

Is there a php function or class that does not require special libraries to be compiled with php in order to unzip a file.

I'm looking for something that processes the unzip and decompression entirely with php.  It seems like all of them require some external extensions compiled with php.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I hate to be *that guy*, but, did you, y'know, try searching for it? "php unzip class" brought me this as the second hit, and it doesn't seem to be using any additional libraries or modules whatsoever: http://www.3scriptz.com/snippets/unzip-on-server-using-php.html

Comment: @Piskvor I hate to be that guy too, but you did not read the requirements.  The link you suggested requires the zlib extensions.  This is what I was wanting to avoid.

Comment: You are correct (and I didn't notice the `zlib` dependency); I was wrong and unnecessarily rude. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've never seen before to be honest. Most hosts will actually install libraries such as zlib for you if you ask (if they're not already) so you can use the functionality

Comment: Don't forget PHP is Turing complete and has disk I/O so it is possible without external libraries.

Comment: and you can always use popen / shell_exec etc.